# llenar un array con valores por defecto si no existe

Tags: php, array

Hola Buenas noches tengo este codigo

```
$total = array();
$months = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

foreach ($months as $value) {
    foreach ($total_clients as $clientes) {
        if($value == $clientes->month){
            $total[$value] = (int)$clientes->total;
        } else {
            $total[$value] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

La variable `$total_clientes` tiene estos valores

```
$total_clients = array(
    array(
        'month' => 5
        'total => 6
    ),
    array(
        'month' => 7
        'total => 12
    ),
    array(
        'month' => 11
        'total => 89
    ),
)
```

Lo que necesito es que el array `$total` se llene solamente con los valores de `$total_clientes`  dependiendo el indice en `$months` tomando como referencia la clave 'month' del array `$total_clients`

algo asi `$total[0,0,0,0,6,0,12,0,0,0,89,0];`

solamente me da esto `Array

```
(
[1] => 0
[2] => 0
[3] => 0
[4] => 0
[5] => 0
[6] => 0
[7] => 0
[8] => 0
[9] => 0
[10] => 0
[11] => 89
[12] => 0
)
```

`

No logro que se llene correctamente, hice prints de los loops pero no funcionan como necesito, me pueden dar una mano, gracias.

Necesito eso para poder pasarlo a un grafico de clientes por meses.

Answer (score 1):

Sólo se está guardando el del valor 11 porque el 11 está en última posición del array. Estás recorriendo el array hasta el final, y aunque guarde los valores 6 y 12, después los estás estableciendo a 0 de nuevo.

```
$total = array();
$months = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

foreach ($months as $value) {
    $bool = false;
    //Recorremos todo el array
    foreach ($total_clients as $clientes) {
        //Comprobamos si el mes coincide. Si coincide sólo guardamos su valor de momento
        if($value == $clientes->month){
            $bool = true;
            $valor = (int)$clientes->total;
        } 
    }
    //Una vez recorrido el array entero, miramos si alguno ha coincidido o no con la variable $bool
    //Si coincidia, asignamos el valor guardado en $valor
    if ($bool == true){
        $total[$value] = $valor;
    } 
    //En caso de que no existiese ese mes en $total_clients le asignamos un 0
    else {
        $total[$value] = 0;
    }
}
```

Esto te puede servir, estableciendo el valor después de recorrer todos los registros del array.

Comment: ya lo solucione, y estan bien las comillas se pueden usar tanto simple como doble

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado @IvoFacundo

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu código, puedes hacer que por cada mes, siempre te inicie el valor en 0. En la posterior comparación se puede reasignar el valor si es necesario. La clausula else ya no es necesaria.

Dentro de if, puedes añadir la sentencia break, de esta manera cesará la ejecución del segundo foreach y el primero pasará a la siguiente iteración.

```
$total = array();
$months = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

foreach($months as $value){
    $total[$value] = 0;
    foreach ($total_clients as $clientes){
        if($value == $clientes['month']){
            $total[$value] = (int)$clientes['total'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, tomar en cuanta sus comentarios para futuros problemas similares, igualmente logre solucinonarlo, con un codigo parecido que hizo @flowen, gracias tambien.

Comment: No hay de que. La solución de @flowen es igualmente  válida. Saludos.